# diff command to get number of different lines only

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu

Can I use the `diff` command to find out how many lines do two files differ in?

I don't want the contextual difference, just the total number of lines that are different between two files. Best if the result is just a single integer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to count differences between two files on linux?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566461/how-to-count-differences-between-two-files-on-linux)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Yes you can, and in true Linux fashion you can use a number of commands piped together to perform the task.

First you need to use the **diff** command, to get the differences in the files.

```
diff file1 file2
```

This will give you an output of a list of changes.  The ones your interested in are the lines prefixed with a '>' symbol

You use the **grep** tool to filter these out as follows

```
diff file1 file2 | grep "^>"
```

finally, once you have a list of the changes your interested in, you simply use the **wc** command in line mode to count the number of changes.

```
diff file1 file2 | grep "^>" | wc -l
```

and you have a perfect example of the philosophy that Linux is all about.

Comment: This will not get lines that are in file1, but not file2, for example if file1 is "hello", and file2 is a blank file, the diff will just be "< hello", so your script will output 0, even though the files are different.

Comment: @AndrewNguyen Here it's related with how to define the difference of lines.

Comment: This approach has a few problems:

First, it will only find lines added by the `file2`, not those added by `file1`.

The second issue is that even if the user looked for both `<` _and_ `>`, it wouldn't provide much clarity regarding which lines were merely _changed_ (which `diff -y` models with a `|` character.)

Comment: Why not just let grep count and let's count the difference regardless of which file has the difference.  

`diff file1 file2 | grep -c -e "^<" -e "^>"`  

In this case, if you reverse the order of the files, you receive the same count.

Answer (score 100):

`diff` can do all the first part of the job but no counting; `wc -l` does the rest:

`diff -y --suppress-common-lines file1 file2 | wc -l`

Comment: You just have to remove the "grep" and this works perfectly, thank you !

Comment: This is the correct answer, while the accepted one is convoluted and plainly wrong.

Comment: Thanks ... this was neat and super helpful!

Comment: If someone was wondering: `-y` is a shorthand for `--side-by-side`, which outputs the files in two columns.

Comment: what if we have to do this for each file in Dir1 and Dir 2? Does not seem to work