# See only the first line change using `diff` command

Tags: shell, diff, git-diff, git-difftool

Say I want to diff two files:

```
diff --ignore-space-change foo.go bar.go
```

is there a way to print only the *first line change* - basically to tell diff to stop working after the first line change is detected - and print that change?

For example, say file1 is:

```
a
b
c
d
```

and file2 is:

```
a
b
y
z
```

then I am looking for a tool that prints something like:

```
<file1
c
>file2
y
```

that's all

Comment: huh? I just want to print the first line diff/change

Comment: Does this answer your question? [diff command to get number of different lines only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27236891/diff-command-to-get-number-of-different-lines-only)

Comment: Do you need to see the change, its location, or just the fact that there is a diff?

Comment: no i am looking for the first line changes only...so if there are 20 lines difference, I just want to see the first

Comment: Simply stating "my question is not a duplicate" without explaining why it is not a duplicate will not get your question reopened.

Comment: look at the OP - the linked question says "just get the line count difference" this question is to print the text difference of the first line change. Very different, it's stated in the question.