# unmatched record count of 2nd column based on 1st column

Tags: unix, scripting, sh

I want to use diff command for below comparasion. Identify different records in column 2 based on column1. 
file1

- 1|Apple
- 2|Banana
- 3|Cat
- 4|Dog

File2

- 1|Apple
- 2|
- 3|Zibra
- 4|Dog

Output should be 2, for column 2; row 2 and 3 have different record.

Comment: Do you want to count the lines that are different? Then it is probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/1566461/10622916

Comment: I think its not similar,,

Comment: I want differece Count only for column2.

Comment: Your your example files show a difference in column 2 only, the rest of the files is identical, so it would be no problem to compare the whole lines. If your case is more complicated, create example files that show a case where it's not sufficient to compare the whole lines.

Comment: I have updated example in my question, I want to identify different records only in 2nd column, first column is same in both the files. In above example mismatch found for Record 2 and Record 3.  I Need Count 2 (Unmatched record of 2nd column)

Comment: If first column is the same in both files then you can simply compare the two files without thinking about columns. The update didn't change this. Try the command from the question in https://stackoverflow.com/q/1566461/10622916

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cut -f2 -d'|' file1 > file1.2ndcolumn
$ cut -f2 -d'|' file2 > file2.2ndcolumn
$ diff file1.2ndcolumn file2.2ndcolumn

2,3c2,3
< Banana
< Cat
---
> 
> Zibra
```

Or, if you just want to count differing lines:

```
$ diff -y --suppress-common-lines file1.2ndcolumn file2.2ndcolumn | wc -l
```

Or, even more quickly, as suggested by @Bodo in a comment:

```
$ diff -y --suppress-common-lines file1 file2 | wc -l
```

since you have no need to consider only the second column, given that the first one is the same in both files...